# Different Machine Codes for same piece of logic

Tags: c, machine-code

Consider the following code

```
char love[4]={'l','o','v','e'};
```

will the machine code of love[1] and *(love+1) be same or different if different why?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It depends entirely on your compiler. You can check by looking at the assembly code generated by your compiler.

Comment: What @Michael said.  However, semantically they are identical.

Comment: Well, because `love[1]` **is actually** `*(love + 1)`, there should be no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking will the reference the same memory location, the answer is yes. So will `*(1+love)` and `1[love]`.

If you're asking if the compiler will generate the same machine language under the covers, that depends entirely on the compiler. The ISO C standard does not dictate that level of detail.

It's generally more concerned with *effects* rather than implementation details.

Given that all four possibilities mean the same thing, I'd be surprised if a compiler generated different machine code under the covers - I'd expect a *decent* compiler to generate the most efficient version for all cases. However, as mentioned above, it's by no means mandatory.